# How do return all columns in Table A where an ID column is present in Table B which contains hundreds of ID columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I understand how to check if Column ID in Table A is present in Table B Column X.

But is there a way to return all rows in Table A in which it does NOT match a single Identifier in Table B?

In reality, Table B contains hundreds of columns.

Table A:

```
+------------+------+--------+----------------+
| Title Name |  ID  | Region | Numeric Column |
+------------+------+--------+----------------+
| Sam        | B021 | NA     |           5.99 |
| Brook      | B026 | EU     |           5.99 |
| Harry      | B032 | KOR    |          10.99 |
+------------+------+--------+----------------+
```

Table B:

```
+------+-------+-------+
| SAM  | BROOK | HARRY |
+------+-------+-------+
| B021 | B024  | B030  |
| 1    | B025  | B031  |
| 2    | 4     |       |
| 3    |       |       |
+------+-------+-------+
```

So in this instance, I would like my query to SELECT Rows 2 & 3 in Table A.

Comment: `SELECT` selects *rows*, not *columns*.  Of course, you can specify the columns (or expressions) that you want, but what is returned are rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a NOT EXISTS could work.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM TableB b
    WHERE a.ID IN (b.SAM, b.BROOK, b.HARRY)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `NOT IN` function to where,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE A 
WHERE col_A NOT IN (SELECT col_A
                    FROM TABLE B)
```

This will return all the rows from `TABLE A` where the val of `col_A` is not in `TABLE B` `col_A`

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I think that one way or another, you will need to enumerate the columns that you want to search.

I would go for the `left join` antipattern, that, allows you to (safely) use the `in` operator:

```
select ta.*
from tableA ta
left join tableB tb on ta.id in (tb.sam, tb.brook, tb.harry) 
where coalesce(tb.sam, tb.brook, tb.harry) is null
```

If you have a column in `tableB` that is `not null` (say, column `never_null`), the `where` clause can be simplfied:

```
select ta.*
from tableA ta
left join tableB tb on ta.id in (tb.sam, tb.brook, tb.harry) 
where tb.never_null is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for.

UNION doesn't work

SO

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablea 
Where `ID` NOT IN (SELECT HARRY FROM tableb)
OR `ID` NOT IN ( SELECT SAM FROM tableb ) 
OR `ID` NOT IN (SELECT HARRY FROM tableb)
```

DBfiddle
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=333a6d2605f881299d888e774fd41c44